# aws s3 glacier storage and transfer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

I am trying to see if there is a way to transfer s3 objects in glacier in one bucket to another bucket but keep the storage type the same? I can restore the glacier object and transfer it, but in the new bucket, the file is saved in standard storage. I would like it to know if there is a way that the file is directly stored in glacier outside of enforcing life cycle policies on the bucket.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't.

Objects can only be copied to another bucket once restored, and objects can only be transitioned into the Glacier storage class by lifecycle policies, not by creating them with this storage class ... which essentially rules out the possibility of the desired outcome for two different reasons.

S3 does not have either a "move" or a "rename" feature -- both of these can only be emulated by copy-and-delete.